# Get file names with complete path in a single txt file using shell script || windows

Tags: shell, batch-file

**Resources:**
So I have multiple folders ordered/sorted by date (could be any other parameter as well)
inside each folder there are sub folders named as numbers and inside each folder there is a "single" test.css file (extension is constant name can be different i.e all files are .css).
so for example sample folder structure can be something like this

```
- project/05.09.2010/00/test.css
- project/05.09.2010/01/test.css
- project/05.09.2010/03/test.css
- project/05.09.2010/09/test.css

- project/07.10.2013/01/test.css
- project/07.10.2013/05/test.css
```

**Requirement:** I want to loop through all folders in order of date and folder number and get list of .css file name in a txt file.
for e.g for above case my output should be:

```
file 'project/05.09.2010/00/test.css'
file 'project/05.09.2010/01/test.css'
file 'project/05.09.2010/03/test.css'
file 'project/05.09.2010/09/test.css'
file 'project/07.10.2013/01/test.css'
file 'project/07.10.2013/05/test.css'
```

I will be performing certain task on those css files later in the same script.

I need code to run in windows batch file.

I am new to shell scripting and have no idea how to approach this scenario.

Comment: please show us code you already tried

Comment: I'm confused.  You present Unix-style file names and you tag [bash], but you say you want code for a Windows batch file.  Windows batch files are not processed via `bash`.

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger file system is windows sorry for the confusion, full file path will be something like this "C://project/05.09.2010/00/test.css" and resultant text file which contains all file paths will have a prefix "file" and then file name. I wanted to tag batch tagged bash instead :(

Comment: @nakashu I have no idea how to proceed, maybe you can suggest me some tutorials or blogs which can guide me how to proceed further.

Comment: you can `dir /s /b *.css` to get the filenames and use a simple `for` loop to add the word `file` and the single qoutes. A big problem is sorting for date (`dir` parameters `/od` or `/on` don't help, because the files are in different folders). I can't imagine a simple solution for that in batch.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephan stated, `dir /s /b "*.css"` will work. However, it does not output it into a text file. This should work:

```
cd "C:\parent directory"
rem set parent directory to the parent directory
dir /s /b "*.css" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\cssfiles.txt
```

This will find all of the .css files and put their names into a text file on your desktop.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir that helps a lot, by the way do you know how do i add prefix file  and quotes around the file name for e.g. output should be :


file 'project/05.09.2010/00/test.css'

file keyword in prefix and path name in quotes